# How to revoke access to system.* table for db user?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm creating a user with the following permissions:

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS U371bqJkJ6sGJ IDENTIFIED WITH sha256_password BY '...O4CqSR1' SETTINGS PROFILE 'default' DEFAULT ROLE user GRANTEES NONE
REVOKE ALL ON *.* FROM U371bqJkJ6sGJ
GRANT SHOW DATABASES ON U371bqJkJ6sGJ.* TO U371bqJkJ6sGJ
GRANT SELECT ON U371bqJkJ6sGJ.* TO U371bqJkJ6sGJ
```

But for some reason, he can read system.* tables, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM system.errors
```

How to revoke access to the system tables?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

here is the only way https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/24887

```sql
create user foo identified by '123';
revoke all on *.* from foo;

create role RO;

CREATE ROW POLICY ro_query_log_filter  ON system.query_log USING 1 AS RESTRICTIVE TO RO;
CREATE ROW POLICY ro_part_log_filter  ON system.part_log USING 1 AS RESTRICTIVE TO RO;
CREATE ROW POLICY ro_trace_log_filter ON  system.trace_log USING 1 AS RESTRICTIVE TO RO;
CREATE ROW POLICY ro_processes_filter ON  system.processes USING 1 AS RESTRICTIVE TO RO;

grant RO to foo;
ALTER USER foo DEFAULT ROLE RO SETTINGS NONE;


clickhouse-client -u  foo --password=123

select count() from system.trace_log;
0 rows in set.

select count() from system.query_log;
0 rows in set.

select count() from system.tables;
0 rows in set.

select query from system.processes;
0 rows in set
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent created users to read system tables by default, you can add this fragment to your config

```xml
<clickhouse>
    <access_control_improvements>
        <users_without_row_policies_can_read_rows>true</users_without_row_policies_can_read_rows>
        <on_cluster_queries_require_cluster_grant>true</on_cluster_queries_require_cluster_grant>
        <select_from_system_db_requires_grant>true</select_from_system_db_requires_grant>
        <select_from_information_schema_requires_grant>true</select_from_information_schema_requires_grant>
        <settings_constraints_replace_previous>true</settings_constraints_replace_previous>
    </access_control_improvements>
</clickhouse>
```

this is taken from [clickhouse repo](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/e9ca8933878e7c13732589f7f490c83c236b4db9/tests/config/config.d/enable_access_control_improvements.xml#L5)